# How to get the check box selected count?

Tags: java, jquery, forms, servlets

I am writing a java servlet application. There I have a dynamic table which i want to get the selected option button count.

[image]

I want to find how many check box values are submitted. Then I can go for a database inserting loop based on this number of submitted check box values.

This is my form code

```
<form role="form" id="user_allowed_unis" name="user_allowed_unis" class="form-horizontal" action="../UnisPerUserCtrl" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="USER_ALLOWED_UNIS">
   <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
       <label class="col-lg-6 control-label">User Email</label>
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input type="text" id="email" data-toggle="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="" maxlength="100">
             </div>
   <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="createLovWindow('Users');" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button></span>
     </div>
 <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>

 <input id="filter" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search University...">
 </div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>University Id</th>
           <th>University</th>
           <th>Selected</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="searchable">
      <%
         UniversityMgt uni=new UniversityMgt();
         ResultSet rs = uni.Get_Universities(dbParam);
         int id = 1;
         while (rs.next()) {    
                String uni_id = rs.getString("id");
                String uni_name = rs.getString("name");

     %>
     <tr>
      <td><%=id%></td>
      <td><%=uni_id%></a></td>
      <td><%=uni_name%></td>
      <td>
         <div class="material-switch">
          <input id="uniOption" name="<%=uni_id%>^uniOption" type="checkbox"/>
         </div>
      </td>
     </tr>
   <input  name="option_count" type="hidden" value="<%=id%>"/>
      <% id++;
       }
       while (rs.previous()) {
    }
   %>
   </tbody>
   </table>
  </form>
```

So far I have tired to send this value as my id value which indicate my table index value but it not success full. It always submit 1 regardless of checked box which i have checked.

following is the result I could get in my servlet.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I'll suggest is write you checkbox code as,

```
<input id="<%=uni_id%>^uniOption" name="uniOption" type="checkbox"/>
```

It means keeping name attribute same for all the checkboxes and id attribute unique for each checkbox. Because in javascript different elements can have same names but id should be unique.

Now, when you submit the page call a JavaScript function and right below code :

```
var checkboxArray = document.getElementsByName("uniOption");

var counter =0;
for(var i=0;i<checkboxArray.length;i++){
if(checkboxArray[i].checked){
// here you will get count of all the checked check boxes
counter++;
}
}
```

Hope this helps!